# quickly subset array if values are matched in dictionary in python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to speed up this function. It checks if the sum of the values of a list exist inside a dictionary. For example, if the value that `x` takes after adding `[0, 1]`, `[1, 0]`, `[0, -1]`, and `[-1, 0]` exist inside `layout`, then remove it as an option in the output. For example:

```
layout = { 0:[2,1], 1:[3,1], 2:[2,2], 3:[6,3] }
x = [2, 1]

possibilities = numpy.zeros(shape=(4,2))
possibilities[0] = [1, 0]
possibilities[1] = [-1, 0]
possibilities[2] = [0, 1]
possibilities[3] = [0, -1]

def myFun(x, layout, possibilities):
    new_possibilities = possibilities + x

    output_direction = []
    for i in new_possibilities:
        i = list(i)
        output_direction.append( (i in layout.values()) )

    output_direction = true_to_false(output_direction)
    possibilities = possibilities[output_direction]
    if possibilities.size == 0:
        possibilities = [0, 0]
        return possibilities
    else:
        return possibilities

# This changes True to False
def true_to_false(y):
output = []
for i in y:
    if i == True:
         output.append((False))
    elif i == False:
        output.append((True))       
return output
```

If I now run this function I get the following output:

```
myFun(x, layout, possibilities)

array([[-1.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.]])
```

The reason I get this output is because `[0, 0] + x` is occupied by `[2,1]` in layout, `[0,1] + x` is occupied by `[2,2]` in layout, and `[1,0] + x` is occupied by `[3,1]` in layout, whereas `[-1, 0] + x` and `[0, -1] + x` do not exist in layout and therefore this is the output result.

This function works fine I would just like it to be faster, since layout can get quite large (tens of thousands of items) and this function is already being run inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## style

Please don't say, e.g., `print((((42))))`, when it suffices to say `print(42)`. The superfluous parentheses make your code harder to read.

## negation

Your negation function could be simplified to this:

```
def true_to_false(y):
    return [not b
            for b in y]
```

But you don't even need that. You can delete the function and avoid the cost of a function call by using `not` when you append:

```
output_direction = []
for i in new_possibilities:
    output_direction.append(list(i) not in layout.values())
possibilities = possibilities[output_direction]
...
```

Even that much is on the verbose side, as it naturally fits in a list comprehension:

```
output_direction = [list(i) not in layout.values()
                    for i in new_possibilities]
```

## speed

The trouble with repeatedly asking whether `i` is within `.values()` is that's a linear scan. If `len(layout.values())` gets to be at all large, you really want to throw those values into a hash map:

```
vals = set(layout.values())
output_direction = [list(i) not in vals
                    for i in new_possibilities]
```

Now the O(n) linear scans become O(1) constant time hash lookups.

If `vals` usually doesn't change between one myFun invocation and the next, then consider passing it in as a parameter alongside `layout`. BTW, you could elide the `x` parameter if the caller is willing to pass in `x + possibilities`.

Have you considered using set intersection instead?

Comment: Thanks for this insightful response. When I run the O(1) solution I run into this error: unhashable type: 'list' any ideas?

Comment: Lists are mutable and therefore unhashable, since hash would change if contents changed. Tuples OTOH are immutable, e.g. tuple(i) is a valid key while list(i) is not.